# Spring security : Ask for login based on custom logic not just URL

Tags: authentication, spring-security, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

We have Spring application(hybris or SAP commerce) where we have secured the URLs with spring security like below-

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/my-account*" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER')" requires-channel="https" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/p/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ACCOUNTADMIN','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" requires-channel="https" />
```

/p/** is the url for products (where ** represent the product id) which does not require login.

**Question** - We need to implement a logic where few products can only be viewed by logged in customer. From Spring security it looks like we can only restrict the authentication based on URL.

I can add a logic in ProductController to check the product requested and if it is a restricted product can add the product id in session and redirect to login page and after login can pull the product id from session and redirect the customer back to product page. But this solution looks very brute.

**Is there a better solution provided by Spring or J2EE in general?**

Answer (score 0):

In Hybris you have the `UserGroups` (for example the `customergroup`) I think I would try to split this customergroup into 2 groups where you can handle your 'special products'.

Your Controller can than check on the specific UserGrop.

**UPDATE**

After login you can use a 'loginSuccessHandler' and implement an own redirect strategy https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login

Comment: yes I am able to redirect to login page based on if customer is anonymous but after login it takes me to homepage instead of product page.